# Invalid column name 'ProposalTypeID'

Tags: sql

Can you please advise me, what am I doing wrong in this stored procedure, it keeps complaining about "ProposalTypeID". Here is my code:

```
 SELECT assessmentecosystemcreditid,
       assessmentversionid,
       dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.managementzoneid,
       (SELECT proposaltypeid
        FROM   tblassessment
        WHERE  assessmentid = (SELECT assessmentid
                               FROM   tblassessmentversion
                               WHERE  assessmentversionid =
               dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.assessmentversionid)) AS
       ProposalTypeID,
       CASE
         WHEN sitevaluecurrentscore <= 17
              AND ( dbo.tblvegetationzone.eecid > 0 )
              AND ( proposaltypeid = 699 ) THEN 0
         ELSE numberofcredits
       END                                                            AS
       NumberOfCreditst
FROM   dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblvegetationtype
               ON dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.vegtypeid =
                  dbo.tblvegetationtype.vegtypeid
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblmanagementzone
               ON dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.managementzoneid =
                  dbo.tblmanagementzone.managementzoneid
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblvegetationzone
               ON dbo.tblvegetationzone.vegetationzoneid =
                  dbo.tblmanagementzone.vegetationzoneid
WHERE  dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.assessmentversionid =
       @AssessmentVersionID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see in your query, you can't reference `proposaltypeid` in your `CASE` statement.

The table `tblassessment` is not in the `FROM` part of the top level `SELECT` statement.

Althought you could have a `proposaltypeid` in your other tables as well, but I assume that in your case this is the cause for the issue.

You're going to need a `LEFT JOIN` (to be sure) at the end, right before your last `WHERE` clause.

I'd change the query to the below code (will generate a messy result set) and then tune it from there (I'm not sure if you have a corresponding column for `assessmentid` in your other tables (which are in the top level `SELECT`).

If you do, then change the ON condition for the `LEFT JOIN` to

`TBA.assessmentid = "referencedTable"."correspondingColumn"`

```
SELECT assessmentecosystemcreditid,
       assessmentversionid,
       dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.managementzoneid,
       (SELECT proposaltypeid
        FROM   tblassessment
        WHERE  assessmentid = (SELECT assessmentid
                               FROM   tblassessmentversion
                               WHERE  assessmentversionid =
            dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.assessmentversionid)) AS ProposalTypeID,
       CASE
         WHEN sitevaluecurrentscore <= 17
              AND ( dbo.tblvegetationzone.eecid > 0 )
              AND ( proposaltypeid = 699 ) THEN 0
         ELSE numberofcredits
       END AS NumberOfCreditst
FROM   dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblvegetationtype
               ON dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.vegtypeid =
                  dbo.tblvegetationtype.vegtypeid
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblmanagementzone
               ON dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.managementzoneid =
                  dbo.tblmanagementzone.managementzoneid
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblvegetationzone
               ON dbo.tblvegetationzone.vegetationzoneid =
                  dbo.tblmanagementzone.vegetationzoneid
       LEFT JOIN tblassessment TBA ON 1 = 1
WHERE  dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.assessmentversionid =
       @AssessmentVersionID
```

It's quite a generic answer, based on the available information, but I think it will put you on the right track.

**Update:**

I believe this query will give you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT assessmentecosystemcreditid,
       assessmentversionid,
       dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.managementzoneid,
       (SELECT proposaltypeid
        FROM   tblassessment
        WHERE  assessmentid = (SELECT assessmentid
                               FROM   tblassessmentversion
                               WHERE  assessmentversionid =
            dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.assessmentversionid)) AS ProposalTypeID,
       CASE
         WHEN sitevaluecurrentscore <= 17
              AND ( dbo.tblvegetationzone.eecid > 0 )
              AND ( proposaltypeid = 699 ) THEN 0
         ELSE numberofcredits
       END AS NumberOfCreditst
FROM   dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblvegetationtype
               ON dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.vegtypeid =
                  dbo.tblvegetationtype.vegtypeid
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblmanagementzone
               ON dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.managementzoneid =
                  dbo.tblmanagementzone.managementzoneid
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblvegetationzone
               ON dbo.tblvegetationzone.vegetationzoneid =
                  dbo.tblmanagementzone.vegetationzoneid

       -- added/modified below JOINs
       INNER JOIN dbo.Assesmentversion AV ON 
         AV.assessmentversionid = dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.assessmentversionid
       INNER JOIN tblassessment TBA ON 
         TBA.AssessmentID = AV.AssessmentID 
WHERE  dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.assessmentversionid =
       @AssessmentVersionID
```

Comment: I have to reference to Assesmentversion table thru AssessmentID,that's the problem now.

Comment: All i know AssessmentVerionID but "Assessment"table don't have assessmentverionID column.But AssessmentVersion table has Assessment ID. that's why i thought use the query to link Assessment table

Comment: (SELECT proposaltypeid
        FROM   tblassessment
        WHERE  assessmentid = (SELECT assessmentid
                               FROM   tblassessmentversion
                               WHERE  assessmentversionid =
            dbo.tblassessmentecosystemcredit.assessmentversionid))